# substitutions for cl_khr_int64_base_atomics

Tags: opencl

I have an ATI Firepro V4800 graphics card which does not support cl_khr_int64_base_atomics. I am trying to adapt the RadixSort algo for long integers. The algo uses atomic_inc, the 64-bit of which is atom_inc, which I cannot use in the kernel. So, my question is, is there a piece of code which performs the same function as atomic_inc which can be used? The piece of kernel code is given below:

```
__kernel void histogram(__global uint* unsortedData,
           __global uint* buckets,
           uint shiftCount,
            __local uint* sharedArray)
{
    size_t localId = get_local_id(0);
    size_t globalId = get_global_id(0);
    size_t groupId = get_group_id(0);
    size_t groupSize = get_local_size(0);

    uint numGroups = get_global_size(0) / get_local_size(0);


    // Initialize shared array to zero //

    sharedArray[localId] = 0;

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

   // Calculate thread-histograms //
    uint value = unsortedData[globalId];
  value =  value >> shiftCount & 0xFFU;    
    atomic_inc(sharedArray+value);


    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    // Copy calculated histogram bin to global memory //

    uint bucketPos = groupId  * groupSize + localId ;
    //uint bucketPos = localId * numGroups + groupId ;
    buckets[bucketPos] = sharedArray[localId];
}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

**Edit:** 
Another way for the same is given in this blogsite: http://suhorukov.blogspot.in/2011/12/opencl-11-atomic-operations-on-floating.html. This gives a very generic implementation of the Atomic Inc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
void atomInc64 (__local uint *counter)
   {
   uint old, carry;

   old = atomic_inc (&counter [0]);
   carry = old == 0xFFFFFFFF;
   atomic_add (&counter [1], carry);
   }
```

Where counter is an array of two 32-bit integers. While the two halves don't increment at exactly the same time, the total should be correct when the program completes.